# How would i make a picture disappear when I hover over other picture in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm kinda experimenting with HTML and I am kinda stuck at my problem. I have 4 pictures next to each other, when I hover over one of them, said picture gets bigger (as I want) and the other pictures shrink and move weirdly from side to side (which I don't want but is manageable).

I would want to make it so that when I am hovering over picture 1, pictures 2, 3, 4 should disappear.

All my attempts ended with either the pictures disappearing completely or not doing anything at all.

```
img {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 120%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border: 5px solid #555;    
}

img:hover {
    width: 2500px;
}



    <div class="zarovnaniobrazek">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=Image">
</div>
<div class="zarovnaniobrazek">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=Another+Image">
</div>

    <div class="zarovnaniobrazek">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=Image">
    </div>
    <div class="zarovnaniobrazek">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=Another+Image">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the elements in a container div, and use the [`:has` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) (`:has` is not currently supported by FF) to hide all all images that are not currently hovered:

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

img:hover {
  width: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container:hover:has(img:hover) img:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="zarovnaniobrazek">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=Image">
  </div>
  <div class="zarovnaniobrazek">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=Another+Image">
  </div>

  <div class="zarovnaniobrazek">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=Image">
  </div>
  <div class="zarovnaniobrazek">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=Another+Image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. 
Just another small question if i may. In my container div i had the pictures set to be next to each other horizontally. However now they are vertically. Would you mind updating your code to make the pictures like that?